# Unity InputField OnValueChanged event shows one less character for InputField.text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, search

I have an `InputField` where I am using it as a search bar. I am not able to search automatically with `OnValueChanged` because initially, the text field will be `""` now if I enter any character like `a`, the `inputField.text` is still `""` instead of `a` because of that the search won't happen until the next character is added.

Is there any way to take the current text at the first hit of the event?

```
public void SearchGame()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText.text) && SearchText.text != "")
            {                    
                var listofvalues = list1.Where(x => x.name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.text.ToLower(), StringComparison.CurrentCulture)).ToList();

                if (listofvalues.Count > 0)
                {                       
                    foreach (var value in listofvalues)
                    {                           
                        //loading 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //No search result
                }
            }
            else
            {
               //stuff                   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LoggingManager.Error(exception);
        }
    }
```

This method is attached to the `On Value Changed` event of the inputfield and `searchText` is the Text of that input field.

Comment: your code please

Comment: @Bijan,I just updated my code...could you help to sort out that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't use dynamic parameter allocation on this event.

```
public void SearchGame(string text)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && text != "")
        {                    
            var listofvalues = list1.Where(x => x.name.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower(), StringComparison.CurrentCulture)).ToList();

            if (listofvalues.Count > 0)
            {                       
                foreach (var value in listofvalues)
                {                           
                    //loading 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //No search result
            }
        }
        else
        {
           //stuff                   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        LoggingManager.Error(exception);
    }
}
```

Note that some events have a parameter which should be included in the handler's signature. e.g. `OnValueChanged` expects a `UnityAction<string>` as its handler or simply a method with that signature `SearchGame(string)`.

So passing `SearchGame()` will ignore the `<string>` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the responce @Bijan,But what should i i give for text?

Comment: @sahithi nothing. UI takes care of that.

Comment: Thank you @Bijan, It helped me a lot :-)

Comment: Hi Bijan, I found a strange behavior in a scenario, the search result gives a list of buttons while I am trying to click on a button from the list, instead of button click event the search happening again and for the second click on the button then corresponding event is hitting.could you help me in figuring it out...

Comment: @sahithi I would love to help but keep in mind this site is not a forum so please provide relevant information and code **in a new question**.