# Unity InputField OnValueChanged event is not woking in Ios

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field

I am trying search functionality through input field. I have a method for which dynamic parameter is given and attached that to `OnValueChanged` event of the input field. The functionality is good in mac and android but when I tested it for iPad it's not working.Is there any settigs has to be chaed for that?

The code as follows:
[Unity InputField OnValueChanged event shows one less character for InputField.text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382621/unity-inputfield-onvaluechanged-event-shows-one-less-character-for-inputfield-te)

Comment: Is suspect that the issue is not `OnValueChanged`. Did you try to debug that function and see if it's being called?

Comment: @Programmer,I tested in unity editor there everything is working good but the same build is not working ipad

Comment: I am asking you to Debug it on iOS. You can use `Debug.Log` in the function that `OnValueChanged` calls. This will let you know if OnValueChanged is being called or not.